# awk transpose lines based on pattern and move (copy) remaining columns after

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, field, multiple-columns, transpose

how to for this problem where mandatory pattern is "nick" based on which its transposed to column and
pattern "MY_" or "MN_" with "MX_" next to it (MX_ pattern should be located on any position in input file under each "NICK" section)

tried out this one
[awk transpose lines based on pattern and move (copy) before current columns with filling empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620717/awk-transpose-lines-based-on-pattern-and-move-copy-before-current-columns-with)
but its limited in what i would like to achieve

input file:

```
NICK: MY_JEFF
MX_NOAA; NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF;
SYS-BRAVO_X3; BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT;
A4:82:8; SEAT_25;
SYS-BRAVO_X2
NICK: MN_CAPTAIN
A4:82:8; NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF;
SYS-BRAVO_X1; BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT;
MX_NOOI
```

desired output:

```
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SYS-BRAVO_X3 
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT 
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA A4:82:8 
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SEAT_25 
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SYS-BRAVO_X2
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI A4:82:8
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI SYS-BRAVO_X1 
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT
```

Comment: nick with small capitals in desired output should be big capitals as input file

Comment: It looks like you want to write a not-so-small parser that would tokenize the input, aggregate and collect it depending on tokens and then output in the specified format. Stackoverflow is a service for small, exact programming problems - your question seems too big for me. If you do not know the tools, there are many great awk introductions on the net. If you want to practice - there are many coding websites on the net. If you want others to do the job for you, it's customary in our culture to offer money in exchange for work - if so, try one of the freelancing sites.

Comment: @tok19 why are you mentioning `nick` (lower case) in your question and comments when it's not present in your sample input nor desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=": |([; ]+)" }
$1 == "NICK" { prt() }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        rec[++nf] = $i
    }
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   i, hdr) {
    for (i=3; i<=nf; i++) {
        if ( rec[i] ~ /^MX/ ) {
            break
        }
    }
    hdr = rec[1] OFS rec[2] OFS rec[i]
    delete rec[i]
    for (i=3; i<=nf; i++) {
        if ( rec[i] ~ /[^[:space:]]/ ) {
            print hdr, rec[i]
        }
    }
    delete rec
    nf = 0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SYS-BRAVO_X3
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA A4:82:8
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SEAT_25
NICK MY_JEFF MX_NOAA SYS-BRAVO_X2
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI A4:82:8
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI NOBASE-INDEX_OUT_FIF
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI SYS-BRAVO_X1
NICK MN_CAPTAIN MX_NOOI BASE-TREE_OUT_OUT
```

Comment: thank you, i moved for now only to this stage where 1st awk will transpose it to lines, then 2nd awk pipe it will move move "MX_" to its proper position and last one missing  to have final output yet

`awk   '{$1=$1} BEGIN {ORS=" "} {gsub(/:|;/,"")} /NICK/&&(NR!=1){printf "\n"};END {print "\n"}1' file  | \
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^MX_/) {t=$i;$i=$3;$3=t; break}}1' `