# awk transpose three patterns in tree into multiple lines

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, transpose, multiline

Hello do anyone might advice how to transpose this multiple lines which are in tree view with 3 patterns

```
listb: harold newu/edu
  tag: 05.8s
    step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
    step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
  tag: 06.8s
    step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024

listb: break version
  tag: 05.8s
    step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720

listb: version/test
  not exist
```

which i need to align into following output

```
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 06.8s step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024
listb: break version  tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720
listb: version/test not exist
```

i tried this partial solution but it lacks for me 3rd matched pattern "step"
[awk transpose lines based on pattern and move (copy) remaining columns after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486551/awk-transpose-lines-based-on-pattern-and-move-copy-remaining-columns-after)

Comment: are the `tag` and `step` lines only indented with space chars? Could you use `tab` chars in the output instead?

Comment: @shellter hi, yes  `tag` and `step` along with `not exist` is indented by space chars, and in output might be `tab" , thats not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for editing your question to show what you've already tried (it makes it much easier to provide potential solutions); here is a 'simpler' approach based on the presence/absence of "step" and "not exist" in each 'block' and only two levels of indentation:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "} /^[[:alpha:]]/ {a = $0} /^  / && !/^   / {gsub(/^ {1,}/, "", $0); b = $0} /^    / {gsub(/^ {1,}/, "", $0); c = $0} /step/ {print a, b, c} /not exist/ {print a, b}' file
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 06.8s step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024
listb: break version tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720
listb: version/test not exist
```

---

Nicer formatting:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS = " "
}

/^[[:alpha:]]/ {
    a = $0
}

/^  / && ! /^   / {
    gsub(/^ {1,}/, "", $0)
    b = $0
}

/^    / {
    gsub(/^ {1,}/, "", $0)
    c = $0
}

/step/ {
    print a, b, c
}

/not exist/ {
    print a, b
}' file
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 06.8s step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024
listb: break version tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720
listb: version/test not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/[^[:space:]].*/) {
    if ( RSTART > prevRstart )      { indent++ }
    else if ( RSTART < prevRstart ) { indent-- }

    val[indent] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    prevRstart  = RSTART

    if ( indent == 3 )      { print val[1], val[2], val[3] }
    else if ( /not exist/ ) { print val[1], val[2] }
    next
}
{ indent = prevRstart = 0 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 06.8s step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024
listb: break version tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720
listb: version/test not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
   {gsub(/^ */,"")}
   /^listb/{list=$0; next}
   /^tag/{tag=$0; next}
   /^step/{print list,tag,$0}
   /^not exist/{print list,$0}
' file

listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f4, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6f5, size: 1024
listb: harold newu/edu tag: 06.8s step: sha256asd6f8, size: 1024
listb: break version tag: 05.8s step: sha256asd6c5, size: 720
listb: version/test not exist
```